# Получить в контроллере значения элементов из формы

Tags: java, spring-boot

Есть форма в html. Как в контроллере получить действия на этой форме? Например если выбрали несколько чекбоксов или нажали кнопку. Как понять и отловить это в контроллере? Эта форма никак не связана с каким-то объектом, а предназначена для выбора нескольких чекбоксов и нажатия на кнопку "Старт", после чего в контроллере будет запущен метод.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-4">

        <div class="form_wrapper">
            <form>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chk01" name="chk01"/>
                <label for="chk01">01</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chk02" name="chk02"/>
                <label for="chk02">02</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chk03" name="chk03"/>
                <label for="chk03">03</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chk04" name="chk04"/>
                <label for="chk04">04</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chk05" name="chk05"/>
                <label for="chk05">05</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chk06" name="chk06"/>
                <label for="chk06">06</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chk07" name="chk07"/>
                <label for="chk07">07</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Старт">
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Контроллер

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    public MainController() {
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String main() {
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/start")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("5555555555");
    }

}
```

Comment: Форма ведь есть. Я выше привела, без скриптов на JS возможно ли передать события с формы в контроллер?

Comment: Мне как раз нужны все события. Т.е. отмечаю нужные чекбоксы и нажимаю Старт и в контроллере отлавливаю какие были нажаты и запускаю метод нужный.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы я отмечала нужные чекбоксы, затем нажимала Старт и начинал отрабатывать метод в контроллере. А в этом методе понимать какие чекбоксы были нажаты и в зависимости от этого выполнять то или иное условие

Comment: В html нет контроллера, или как?

Comment: Добавила в вопрос контроллер. Отметить пару чекбоксов и по нажатию на Старт как например отловить в методе test события и выполнить system.out.pringln?

Comment: Зачем вы поставили префих th? На странице нет ни одного елемента с этим префиксом.

Comment: Для thymeleaf имеете ввиду? Это для подключения стилей

Comment: Каких стилей? К вам в коде нет никаких стилей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим, форма хранится в файле `select.html` и открывается по `/select`, тогда я предлагаю такой контроллер (указаны не все чекбоксы):

```
@Controller
public class Select {
    @GetMapping("/select")
    public String select(
            @RequestParam(required = false) boolean chk01,
            @RequestParam(required = false) boolean chk02,
            @RequestParam(required = false) boolean chk03
    ) {
        if (chk01) System.out.println("chk01");
        if (chk02) System.out.println("chk02");
        if (chk03) System.out.println("chk03");
        return "select";
    }
}
```

Т.к в форме нет атрибута `action` браузер отправит запрос на тот же адрес по которому получ эту форму, а из-за отсутсвия атрибута `method`, будет использоваться дефолтный `GET`. В итоге, запрос будет иметь вид типа
`GET hhttp://localhost:8080/select?chk01=on&chk03=on` если выбраны 1 и 3 варианты.

Параметры после `?` получаем с помощью аннотации`@RequestParam`; значение  будет преобразовываться в `true` при выборе (передаётся `on`); имя параметра метода соответсвует атрибуту `name`.

Для нормальной обработки запроса `GET` на получения страницы с формой параметры отмечены как необязательные.

Comment: А если форма открывается по "/" сразу на главной?

Comment: поменять mapping на "/"

Comment: @PostMapping("/")
    public String start(@RequestParam(required = false) boolean chk01,
                        @RequestParam(required = false) boolean chk02,
                        @RequestParam(required = false) boolean chk03) {
        if (chk01) System.out.println("chk01");
        if (chk02) System.out.println("chk02");
        if (chk03) System.out.println("chk03");
        return "/";
    } так прописала ничего не выводит.

Comment: в форме нет  атрибута `method`, будет использоваться дефолтный `GET`. если у вас `@PostMapping`, то и в форме надо указать `method="POST"`

Comment: когда я отвечал, не увидил, что вы дополнили вопрос контроллером. а в нём ещё и url обработки оформы другой. значит надо ещё `action` указать.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо! У меня выдавал ошибку что нет шаблона. "/" когда нажимала кнопку на форме, оказывается нужно было сделать редриект return "redirect:/"

Comment: Еще небольшой вопрос. А если ни один чекбокс не выбран как на страницу передать ошибку? Вроде BindingResult bindingResult используется для передачи ошибок, если форма связана с каким-то объектов вроде понятно как делать, а в моем случае не знаю

Comment: создайте новый вопрос, опишите что есть на данный момент, что хотите получить, с чем проблемы

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1508995/Обработка-ошибок-с-формы-в-контроллере добавила